# how to resize/fit image in jframe?

Tags: java, swing

I just wanted to know how to simply fit the [logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DbTH.png) in the desired size.
Disclaimer: this is just a bootleg program.

Comment: [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928); [Resizing icon to fit on JButton in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798156/resizing-icon-to-fit-on-jbutton-in-java/25798462#25798462); [Scale the ImageIcon automatically to label size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)

Comment: [Getting the size of a JButton inside a JPanel that has a GridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160101/getting-the-size-of-a-jbutton-inside-a-jpanel-that-has-a-gridlayout/29160938#29160938)